# Excel VBA to select from drop-down list

Tags: excel, vba

I have written a VBA Macro in Excel which creates spreadsheets from a template and updates values for individual spreadsheets based on options in a drop down list.

How can I use VBA to choose the first option in the list?

Answer (score 1):

Say your drop down list is named `myList`, the way to select items programmatically is by using the `.ListIndex` property of the object. Which means:

```
myList.ListIndex = j
```

where j goes from `0` (first element) to `n-1` (last element). In your case:

```
myList.ListIndex = 0
```

will select the first item.

**IF THE CONTROL IS IN THE SPREADSHEET**:

in that case the code is slightly different:

```
With Sheets("Sheet1").Shapes("Region").ControlFormat
    .ListIndex = 0
End With
```

Comment: I am getting the error: "Object variable or With block variable not set" after including `myList.ListIndex = 0`

Comment: Are you namely writing `myList.ListIndex=0` or are you replacing `myList` with the actual name of your dropdown object?

Comment: That is the error - "Object variable or With block variable not set" - should I have defined the list earlier in the code?

Comment: I had already named the list - its called Region so my code reads `region.listindex = 0` and I am getting the error above. I meant should the list be detfined earlier in the code - I don't know what the error means. Cheers

Comment: Sorry @amymon87, just figured out the syntax is slightly different between userforms and controls. Please see edit in my question and let me know if you have troubles (note: I assume the control is on Sheet1 and that is already populated with some values)

Comment: Thanks so much but I am now getting an error saying "The item with the specified name wasn't found". I have used `With Sheets("Control").Shapes("Region").ControlFormat
    .ListIndex = 0
End With` This references the sheet named "Control" and goes to my list box which has a named range "Region" and have used Data Validation with 3 regions, NSW, QLD and WA as options and I want to choose the first one in the list.

Comment: Check out if the name "Region" is not mispelled, otherwise I would suggest you to add a watcher and go in debug, cannot help you much from here :(

Comment: Could not get this to work and was informed that it cannot be done because I used data validation to make the list.